# Image is not showing in div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do image light box using JavaScript. Here is my html code

```
<div id="lightbox2">

</div>
<div id="lightbox">
    <button onclick="lgBox('www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg')"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" alt=""></button>

</div>
```

I am sending current clicked link as a parameter in `lgBox` function. 
Here is my Js function.

```
    function lgBox(url){
    var u = url;
    alert(u);
    document.getElementById("lightbox2").innerHTML="<img src='u' />";
    document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display="none";

}
```

It shows the url in alert box properly that I passed. 
But why this link is not working here `"<img src='u' />";`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, your `u` is just part of the string. Either make string interpolation or string concatination, eg: `innerHTML="<img src='" + u + "' />";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method what you are using is wrong as it places the string `u` as it is in the src tag. You want to replace this `u` with the actual value of that variable. **See below:**

```
function lgBox(url){
var u = url;
alert(u);
//this is wrong and will throw an error in console (404)
document.getElementById("lightbox2").innerHTML="<img src='u' />";
document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display="none";
}
```

Instead of the above you should do something like this

```
function lgBox(url){
var u = url;
alert(u);
//ES6 template literals or if this is not supported then you can use 
//concatenation also.
document.getElementById("lightbox2").innerHTML=`<img src=${u} />`;
document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. A lot of answer is given. And this one is best.

Comment: Great. Try not to repeat such a mistake in future :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to **concat** the var u to the string with + like this:

```
'<img src="' + u + '" />'
```

In your code:

```
function lgBox(url){
    var u = url;
    alert(u);
    document.getElementById("lightbox2").innerHTML='<img src="' + u + '" />';
    document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display="none";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply passe the `u` string in the html tag, you have to actually concatenate the url like this :

`document.getElementById("lightbox2").innerHTML = '<img src="' + u + '" />';`